# Running gunicorn from dockerfile not working, but not showing in interactive bash

Tags: docker, nginx, gunicorn

In this dockerfile, we have:

```
EXPOSE 5000
RUN gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000
RUN /usr/sbin/nginx
```

However, when I do from docker running image:

```
root@594ac39e8115:/# ps -x
```

I get

```
PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
      1 pts/0    Ss     0:00 bash
     10 pts/0    R+     0:00 ps -x
```

But if I run:

```
root@594ac39e8115:/# gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 && /usr/sbin/nginx
```

I get:

```
PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
      1 pts/0    Ss     0:00 bash
     15 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000
     16 ?        Ss     0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
     26 ?        S      0:02 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000
     27 ?        S      0:02 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000
     28 ?        S      0:02 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000
     29 ?        S      0:02 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000
    314 pts/0    R+     0:00 ps -x
```

And the app replies to curl requests.

Why isn't the dockerfile able to correctly initialize the gunicorn instances and nginx reverse proxy server?

Comment: You're trying to `RUN` the server as part of the image build; Docker promptly kills it and creates a filesystem snapshot, and it's not still running when you `docker run` the container later.  With this setup you want _two_ containers, one running the Python application and one the Nginx reverse proxy, each with a single `CMD` running a single process in the foreground.

Comment: @DavidMaze considering I'm very new to all of this... What would be the best way to do what you're suggesting?